# What I need to know: How to connect to a NON-MICROSOFT web API via Oauth

Tags: oauth

I am a junior developer and have done several cool things with Microsoft APIs; connecting to APIs there is a breeze because you can get OAuth tokens quite easily and any permissions you might need are covered by the Microsoft Graph spectrum, where you basically have a GUI to handpick each permission - access is then granted via an admin and voilá, you can access all the goods with any programming language really.

How does that work OUTSIDE the world of Microsoft though? I will have to work on a "normal" web API that has no connection to MS tools whatsoever, and I know there is no generic answer to that, but can someone maybe post a step-by-step description what is needed in laymen terms? The reason being that I am supposed to be part of a meeting where access is being discussed and I have no idea what kinds of questions I will have to ask :D

I will want to send an HTTP request to the API and am wondering about:

- how OAuth tokens are usually generated
- how permissions are granted for the scope of the API call
- what else might be lurking :D

Comment: Hey there! Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn what questions are a good fit for Stack Overflow. The community is here to help you but with concrete problems. There are plenty of OAuth resources out there that will help you understand the basics of OAuth and API security.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski I get where you're coming from but it _is_ a concrete problem, i.e. "create a new application", "obtain client ID and secret" etc. Never mind, I answered it myself and posted it in case anyone else needs something like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Register your application with the API provider:

   1. Go to the API provider's developer portal or documentation and create a new application.
   2. Follow the instructions to create the application, which may include providing details about your application such as the name, description, and website.
   3. Once you have created the application, the API provider should provide you with a client ID and a client secret. Make sure to keep these secret and secure, as they will be used to authenticate your application when making API requests.
2. Obtain authorization from the user:

   1. Redirect the user to the API provider's authorization page. This typically involves constructing an authorization URL that includes your client ID, the scope of access requested, and a redirect URL that the user will be redirected to after authorizing the access.
   2. The user will be asked to grant or deny permission for your application to access their data through the API.
   3. If the user grants permission, they will be redirected back to your application's redirect URL with an authorization code.
3. Request an access token:

   1. Use the authorization code to request an access token from the API provider. This typically involves making a POST request to a specific acess token API endpoint with the authorization code, your client ID, client secret, and redirect URL as parameters.
   2. If the request is successful, the API provider should respond with an access token.
4. Make API requests:

   1. Use the access token to authenticate your application when making API requests. Typically, you will include the access token as an HTTP header or query parameter in each API request.
      The specific API endpoints and request parameters will depend on the API you are connecting to. Refer to the API provider's documentation for details on how to make API requests.